# Gnome-tweak-tool kali linux 2019 "shell not installed or running"

Tags: gnome, kali-linux, theme

So I was trying to switch up the theme for my new kali linux 2019.4 virtual machine. I installed `gnome-tweak-tool` package for the task. However, when I run it by typing `gnome-tweaks` in the command line, it gives this error:

```
WARNING : Shell not installed or running  
WARNING : Shell not running  
NoneType: None  
WARNING : Error detecting shell  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gtweak/tweaks/tweak_group_shell_extensions.py", line 217, in __init__
raise Exception("Shell not running or DBus service not available")  
Exception: Shell not running or DBus service not available
```

The gnome-tweaks windows shows up, but the changes don't actually take effect when I try to change the wallpaper.

I tried to run `gnome-shell` just to see what it did, and it gives me this:

```
can't load /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/spa/support/libspa-support.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/spa/support/libspa-support.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory  
Window manager warning: Display “:0” already has a window manager; try using the --replace option to replace the current window manager.
(gnome-shell:2831): mutter-ERROR **: 18:55:08.350: Failed to start Xwayland: Failed to acquire window manager ownership  
== Stack trace for context 0x560714042340 ==  
Trace/breakpoint trap
```

I tried doing `gnome-shell --replace` but the machine just crashes. Any idea how to fix this? I really just want to change my theme. Been googling for days now. Any pointers or suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Kali Linux distribution you have is the XFCE(default), download the GNOME version to use GNOME Tweaks.